# got forbidden login in on Kie-server

Tags: wildfly, kie, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server, kie-server

I'm following one tutorial to get kie-drools-workbench and kie-server working: https://www.intertech.com/Blog/simple-setup-of-drools-kie-workbench-and-kie-server-in-one-wildfly-instance/

Installed wildfly and downloaded the *kie-server-6.4.0.Final-ee7 and kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.4.0.Final-wildfly8* and move them to **C:\apps\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments**

Created user jeff with roles admin and developer on wildfly like the tutorial shows.

on CMD start standalone which starts wildfly 8.2.1
got at C:\apps\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments
  - kie drools .war and .deployed
  - kie server 64.0 .war and .deployed

Login with jeff user at administration on http://localhost:8080/ and got redirected to http://localhost:9990/console/App.html#home

Under deployments I have the kie-server and kie-drools enabled, how can I access them?

I can land to the kie Workbench with kie server user at http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.4.0.Final-wildfly8/kie-drools-wb.html but I can't land on the kie-server, got forbidden with user jeff or user kieserver at http://localhost:8080/kie-server-6.4.0.Final-ee7/services/rest/server/containers

I don't find why, I login with jeff user but got forbidden and have to restart all to try another user / pass, like kieserver user.

I access kie-workbench, loggin with kieserver user and under deploy -> rule deployments -> remote servers got the kie server link, but the problem is the same, can't access it. forbidden and only have one shot to get the user pass right, or else I have to restart it.

The objective is to work better with drools rules and debug rules the best way, get to check which fact are loaded and which rules are applied to each fact..
Does anyone got the same issue? Or got something like what I need working?

EDIT: I can work with rules on kie-Drools-wb, the question is, do I really need the kie server to start?  Because I only need to create rules based one a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution.

I don't need to use the server, the server is wildfly and should be running by then, the drools Workbench as explained on the tutorial works and the demo project is the sandbox.

This is only for academic purposes.